# Is the use of "booking-hotel agancy" in the following question correct lexically?

Tags: word-choice

Where is there  a booking-hotel counter or agancy in this airport?

Comment: BTW "agency" is spelled with an "e".

Comment: If what you mean is a counter/agency where you may book a hotel, what you want to say is *hotel booking counter/agency*. Technically that's a little ambiguous: it might be either a counter for booking hotels or a booking counter maintained by a specific hotel; but in practice the context will make clear what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite right.  'Hotel' has to go before 'booking'.  I'm not sure what question you're trying to ask, but one of these should be what you want.

> "Is there a hotel booking counter in this airport?" - you want
>   to know if a counter exists.
>
> "Where is the hotel booking counter in this airport?" - there is a
>   counter and you want to know where it is.

It can also be called the hotel reservation counter.